# Is every greatest element a maximal element as well?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

greatest element(x) :  (xRy)

maximal element (x) :  (~yPx)

I think that every greatest element should be the maximal element as well because with  maximal element we have a strict condition whereas in greatest its a weak one , but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: If **the** greatest element (a.k.a. *the maximum*) exists, then it is **a** maximal element indeed (the only one).

Comment: For reference: $$x\text{ is a (the) greatest element of }(A,\le)\iff \forall y\in A,\ y\le x$$$$x\text{ is a maximal element of }(A,\le)\iff \forall y\in A,\ x=y\vee \neg(x\le y)$$ The first one is stronger, because if $x$ satisfies it and $x\le y$ for some $y$, then...

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question in the title of your question is: yes.

Let $R$ denote a partial order (reflexive, transitive and antisymmetric) on a set $A$.

If an element $a$ exists such that $bRa$ is true for *every* $b\in A$ then this element is in this context a **greatest element**.

(Note: such element does not necessarily exist)

This element $a$ would by definition be **maximal** if $aRb$ implies that $a=b$.

Now assume that element $a$ is not maximal. Then some $b\in A-\{a\}$ must exist with $aRb$. We allready know that $bRa$ (because $a$ is a greatest element) and the fact that $R$ is antisymmetric then allows the conclusion that $b=a$. A contradiction is found and it is proved now that $a$ is maximal.

To make things complete: with the same argument it can be shown that $a$ is unique as greatest element, so that we can call it **the greatest element**. Secondly if there is indeed a greatest element then it is also unique as maximal element.